# Trouble Getting Meaningful Information from TF Lite 3D Input/Output Model on Arduino Hardware

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, arduino, tensorflow-lite

My application has 20 sensor variables, And I'm trying to generate just 1 output from 20 inputs.
I'm deploying my model on arduino portenta H7 platform.

I've successfully implemented a simple RNN model in keras, and exported it to .h file. I've than successfully deployed my model on arduino hardware. But it's output is not entirely accurate (due to it's simplicity).
Input for this model is `[1, 20]`, and model's output is `[1, 1]`. I used the following code to assign and handle input/output tensors:

```
#include <TensorFlowLite.h>
#include "constants.h"
#include "main_functions.h"
#include "model.h"
#include "output_handler.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_log.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/system_setup.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"

// Globals, used for compatibility with Arduino-style sketches.
namespace {
    const tflite::Model* model = nullptr;
    tflite::MicroInterpreter* interpreter = nullptr;
    //TfLiteTensor* model_input = nullptr;
    //TfLiteTensor* model_output = nullptr;
    constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 128 * 1024;  // MEMORY SIZE
    // Keep aligned to 16 bytes for CMSIS
    alignas(16) uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];
}  // namespace

void setup() {
    tflite::InitializeTarget();
    // Map the model into a usable data structure. This doesn't involve any
    // copying or parsing, it's a very lightweight operation.
    model = tflite::GetModel(g_model);
    if (model->version() != TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION) {
        MicroPrintf(
            "Model provided is schema version %d not equal "
            "to supported version %d.",
            model->version(), TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION);
        return;
    }

    // This pulls in all the operation implementations we need.
    // NOLINTNEXTLINE(runtime-global-variables)
    static tflite::AllOpsResolver resolver;

    // Build an interpreter to run the model with.
    static tflite::MicroInterpreter static_interpreter(model, resolver, tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize);
    interpreter = &static_interpreter;

    // Allocate memory from the tensor_arena for the model's tensors.
    TfLiteStatus allocate_status = interpreter->AllocateTensors();
    if (allocate_status != kTfLiteOk) {
        MicroPrintf("AllocateTensors() failed");
        return;
    }

    // Obtain pointers to the model's input and output tensors.
    model_input = interpreter->input(0);
    model_output = interpreter->output(0);
}

bool INVOKE(void*) { /////// EXECUTED EVERY 25ms ///////
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        model_input->data.f[j] = sensorData[j];

        TfLiteStatus invoke_status = interpreter->Invoke();
        if (invoke_status != kTfLiteOk) {
            MicroPrintf("Invoke failed");
            return false;
        }

        // Extract single float output
        ModelOutput = ExtractOutputData(model_output->data.f);
    }

    float ExtractOutputData(const float* output_data) {
        return output_data[0];
    }
}
```

INVOKE function gets called every 25ms with fresh sample.

So, I than built a more accurate ML model in keras (using 1D convolutions), and again implemented the model's h file to my arduino program.
This model uses 1D convolutions, so the input is `[1,1,20]`, and output is `[1,1,1]`.
I am unable to get any meaningful information from this model on arduino, meanwhile keras gives good results..
I am using the same code I did for the RNN network above, and the model's output is always 0.00000000.
My question is do I need to reshape my sensor data structure in arduino to have `[1,1,20]` format?
And, do how do I read the model's output, if it has 3 dimensions? I am only interested in the latter dimension (`[1,1,1]`).

I've tried accessing output tensors from `output_data[0]` to `output_data[60]`, and noticed, that the first 0-24 output tensors are all 0, while tensors from 24-60 are some numbers that change depending on input data, but not in a meaningful way.

I've now tried using the following layer in front of all CNN layers:

`model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,20), input_shape=(20,)))`

and the following layer after all layers:

`model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())`

**with this 2 added layers I managed to get the following input shape:**

````
   'index': 0,
   'shape': array([ 1, 20], dtype=int32),
   'shape_signature': array([-1, 20], dtype=int32),
   'dtype': numpy.float32,
   'quantization': (0.0, 0),
   'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
    'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
    'quantized_dimension': 0},
   'sparsity_parameters': {}}]```



**and the following output shape:**

```[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0',
   'index': 42,
   'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
   'shape_signature': array([-1,  1], dtype=int32),
   'dtype': numpy.float32,
   'quantization': (0.0, 0),
   'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
    'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
    'quantized_dimension': 0},
   'sparsity_parameters': {}}]```


so now I've managed to get input shape to [1 20] and output to [1 1].
However, when I run the model on arduino hardware, I get output value of cca **17000.3213**, meanwhile in keras I get output between 0 and 5...

What could be the cause? I'm not using any quantization..
````